# How can I solve this error? I write the link of button like this but I found this error,

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<a  class="btn-danger" href="<? php echo SITEURL;?>admin/delete-admin.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"> Delete </a>
```

I write the link  of a button like this but I found this error

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.3.30 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: This part `<? php echo SITEURL;?>` is probably causing problem.

Comment: <?php echo SITEURL; ?> use like this

Answer (score 3):

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

It looks like an Apache error, you have to check your vhost.

And for the PHP, you have to write

```
<a class="btn-danger" href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/delete-admin.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"> Delete </a>
```

Or, shorter way

```
<a class="btn-danger" href="<?= SITEURL; ?>admin/delete-admin.php?id=<?= $id; ?>"> Delete </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use template engines or frameworks like Laravel?

and also try this:

```html
<a  class="btn-danger" href="/admin/delete-admin.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"> Delete </a>
```